# Offering subdomains what are the risks?

Tags: subdomain, content

I am interested in offering subdomains to people who want them e.g. `helloworld.mydomain.com` or `blah.mydomain.com`.

It is pretty much how WordPress or Blogspot handle their subdomains but I would not be hosting anything - just pointing to the person's website host location.

If somebody was to upload illegal content to `helloworld.mydomain.com` - would all sites under `mydomain.com` suffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only hosting the domain then illegal content is not something you should concern yourself too much since the appropriate authorities will know how to lookup the A records where the files are hosted. It can however look crappy on your branding if you want one.